# Project Tango Demo and Example Code Git Repos

Tags: google-project-tango

Before creating and posting my own git repos of the sample/demo code does anyone know if the ATAP Tango dev relations team is posting the demos and dowloadable code on any accessible git repos?

Otherwise I'm likely to investigate setting up my own so I can look at diffs over time (especially to any of the shared lib code).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what sample, or demo, code you're looking for. All of the C and Java sample code can be found on a public github repository, which is linked below.

Unity sample code is released in the form of the SDK package with each new Tango developer release. While source code for Unity samples will be available for each major release, demos will not. Binaries for all demos can be found on the official developer page, linked below.

Official C sample repository -> https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c
Official Java sample repository -> https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java
Official Unity SDK package and binaries -> https://developers.google.com/project-tango/downloads
Official release notes and known issues -> https://developers.google.com/project-tango/downloads

Cheers,
Chase

Answer (score 1):

I did find two projects under github:
https://github.com/googlesamples?query=tango